# Weblogic 10.3.5 doesn't get start

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I am not able to start the weblogic 10.3.5 server, it throws the below error in console (just this message, nothing else in the console).

```
\Enterprise was unexpected at this time.
```

I tried in STS 3.3.0 and in eclipse 3.8.0. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, it doesn't fix. I am able to start the 10.3.26 weblogic and tomcat servers from eclipse/sts. Does the problem in eclipse install or am i missing some configuration?

Comment: Can you provide me the logs...(or) please let me know how you are starting your server...

Comment: Vana, There is no other details. That's only entry in the console log and log file. I started from eclipse ide, by clicking start in server view.